# What is difference between catalog and feature in geomesa?

Tags: geomesa

I am trying to understand how a catalog(table) and features differs. Till now what I can understand is we can create multiple features in a single catalog, but why I need to do so?. Why I can't create features independently?. What is being achieved doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMesa allows for feature types to share tables.  In the event that some feature types were very small, it would reduce the number of different Accumulo tables created.

More generally, this allows for grouping features into similarly named tables for administration (using Accumulo namespaces), security (various users can be granted permissions based on namespaces and/or tablenames), and simplicity.

This is much the same way that a PostgreSQL database can have multiple tables.

Comment: Where I can find examples of how creating different features in a catalog can help

Comment: I don't think there are particular examples that will show this.  Broadly, different data types are best represented by different SimpleFeatureTypes.  Each of those feature types is named and stored separately.  (For instance, there might be a twitter feature type and an OSM feature type.)  This explains why one needs more than one feature type.

Secondly, given multiple feature types, one may wish to store them in a separate catalogs for administrative reasons.  All the table managed by a catalog will have names which will match a regular expression, and that will simplify some operations.